# Timer to display HH:MM:SS on a label

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Trying to display a run-time that will display HH:MM:SS so far i got the SS part working. But once it go to 60 it will jump back to 00.

The code i got so far is:

```
DateTime startTime;
startTime = DateTime.Now;
timer1.Tick += (s, ev) => { lb_runnerStatus.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", (DateTime.Now - startTime).Seconds); };
startTime = DateTime.Now;
timer1.Interval = 100;       // every 1/10 of a second
timer1.Start();
```

Is it possible to get it to display 00:00:01 and when its at 1 minute 00:01:00 and so on.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24995/convert-timespan-to-readable-text shows you how to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote the accepted answer below is so much better suited for my needs just one line of code instead of many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply call `.ToString()` method on `TimeSpan` instance and it will return `string` in *HH:MM:SS* format:

```
lb_runnerStatus.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString();
```

If you need more advanced formatting, use `.ToString(string format)` overload, where you can specify desired format either with [Standard TimeSpan Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) or [Custom TimeSpan Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings), for example following will include milliseconds:

```
lb_runnerStatus.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff");
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you